# Clear local storage is not working in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

Clear local storage when click on logout button is not working, also I am not doing it with controller files I use only **.ts** and **.HTML** also I am having error while making function does there nay method to do it without making function too? Any feature of Angular?

Here is my **HTML file**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 19.315" width="20">
                    <g id="logout"  transform="translate(0
                       -1.66)" > </svg>
```

Here is my **ts file**

```
  public articlepara = { clientid: localStorage.getItem('storageselectedclient'), page: 1, type: 'All', keytype: '', sortdate: 'asc', sortpub: '', sortnews: '', fromdate: this.fromdate, todate: this.todate, publicationFilter: '', sortprominence: '' }
  user = {
    email: localStorage.getItem('email')
  }


  constructor(public article: ArticleService, http: HttpClient, elementRef: ElementRef, public _client: ClientService, private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService, private helper: HelperService, excelService: ExcelService, private filterPipe: FilterPipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    $("#reset").hide();
    var self = this;
    // $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dateclick").click(function () {
      $('#rangeCal').toggle();
    })
    updateConfig();
    function updateConfig() {
      var options: { dateLimit: String } = {
        dateLimit: ""
        //,minDate: moment().subtract(365, 'days') , maxDate: moment() 
      };
      $('#config-demo').daterangepicker(options, function (start, end, label) {

        var startDateRange = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var endDateRange = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        self.articlepara.todate = endDateRange;
        self.articlepara.fromdate = startDateRange;
        self.spinnerService.show();

        self.isActiveToday = false;
        self.isActive7Days = false;
        self.isActiveYesterday = false;
        self.isActivedaterange = true;
      });
    }
    //  });

    this.articlepara.type = 'ALL';
    this.articlepara.keytype = '';
    // this.articlepara.prominance = '';
    // this.articlepara.company = '';
    // this.articlepara.author = '';
    this.articlepara.publicationFilter = '';

    this.Clients();  //uncomment for client list
    this.selectedclient = localStorage.getItem('storageselectedclient');

    this.spinnerService.show();

  }
  Clients() {
    //console.log(this.user);
    // this.spinnerService.show();
    this._client.getClients(this.user)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          // console.log(res);
          this.clientlist = res;
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        },
        () => {
          // this.getallarticles();
          this.spinnerService.show();
          this.getUserDetails();
        }
      )
  }
  getUserDetails() {
    var postData = {
      clientid: localStorage.getItem('storageselectedclient'),
      email: localStorage.getItem('email')
    }

    this.article.getUserDetails(postData)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          // console.log(res);
          this.userdetails = res[0];
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      )
    this.getUserClientDetails();
  }
  getUserClientDetails() {
    var postData = {
      clientid: localStorage.getItem('storageselectedclient')
    }

    this.article.getUserClientDetails(postData)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          // console.log(res);
          this.userClientdetails = res[0];
          this.spinnerService.hide();
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      )
  }
  //=======================change selectd client form dropdownlist=============================//
  changeclient(value) {
    localStorage.setItem('storageselectedclient', value);
    localStorage.removeItem('storageselectedclient')
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.getUserDetails();
  }
```

Comment: which is your localstorage items removing function?

Comment: getting issues in making function any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to **drop** an item from localStorage use

```
localStorage.removeItem("key_name");
```

to **clear** local storage i.e to empty it (to remove all keys stored in local storage)

```
localStorage.clear();
```

I think problem in your code is

1. You are not Clearing local storage or item stored in local storage anywhere
2. Even if you follow 1 st point you have to call your specific method from component on click of logout button and clear local storage in that method in the component

here is how you do it

In HTML:

logout.component.html

```
<button id="logout" (click)="logoutUser()">Logout</button>
```

In component:

logout.component.ts

```
//your rest component code

logoutUser(){

    //clear local storage
    localStorage.clear();

    //or
    //remove an key from local storage
    localStorage.removeItem("your_key);

    //things that you want to do for logout


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no relative code for what you are asking here, but if you want to remove something from local storage you should be using `localStorage.removeItem('keyOfYourItem')`;

Answer (score -1):

localStorage.removeItem('put your key here');

Answer (score -1):

You can make a function for removing all the keys

```
  removeAllLocalStorage() {
        localStorage.removeItem('key1');
        localStorage.removeItem('key2');
        localStorage.removeItem('key3');
        localStorage.removeItem('key4');
    }
```

Now call this function on logout to clear your storage